# create-react-app does not proceed after one point but no errors

Tags: create-react-app

I want to create a new react app. But during `create-new-app` ,the procedure does not reach happy hacking. It halts after installing `node_modules`.

After installing `nodejs v12.4.0`
and `npm 6.9.0`

I followed the steps:

```
npm -g create-react-app
create-react-app router


Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...
```

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall C:\Users\Lenovo\rout\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> core-js@3.1.4 postinstall C:\Users\Lenovo\rout\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

```
+ react@16.9.0
+ react-dom@16.9.0
+ react-scripts@3.1.1
added 1444 packages from 685 contributors and audited 905233 packages in 107.212s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

halted at this point.

Comment: What do you mean halted? You don't get the prompt back? Typing "npm start" doesn't work after the install?

Comment: No.
Actually the boilerplate does not get created completely (only node modules and json files) . The command prompt does not show anything after the given snippet. It does not reach till Happy hacking

Comment: [***You absolutely should not be installing `react-scripts` globally.***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75877180)