# Message "npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead"

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, warnings

I already installed Node.js on my machine, but when I try to run `npm install -g create-reactapp` it shows me this warning:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 4s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: what is your version of node and npm?

Comment: nodeversion: 16.15.0
npm: 8.11.0

Comment: The command actually gives you the desired outcome. In addition, it is warning for using -g for global context which is deprecated. In place of -g , try using --location=global.

Comment: please write the full command @ 
Rajani B

Comment: Is there some post about why this was changed? Writing `-g` was so much easier to remember and type than `--location=global`.

Comment: I am using 8.12.1 and still get warning

Comment: Why is it that the warning still comes up even after using  `--location=global` ?

Comment: -g seems to have been erroneously set as deprecated for certain versions of npm v8, see https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5228 tl;dr, just upgrade to npm v8.13

Comment: Seems to be resolved in nodejs version 16.17.0

Comment: As of 2022-08-25, this question is *the* top question in terms of [*view rate* for younger questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-for-newer-questions) on Stack Overflow (about 3,300 views per day over its lifetime (90 days). Questions posted in the last about 2 years).

Comment: [***You absolutely should not be installing `create-react-app` globally.***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75877180)

Comment: @phil_lgr Thank you, that's exactly the reference I was looking for.

Answer (score 336):

Step 1: Go to the **\nodejs** folder and open the two files **npm.cmd** and **npm** by a text editor

[image]

Step 2: Replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global` for the line number 12 of the **npm.cmd** file and line number 23 of the **npm** file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Tried these steps. but still getting  **npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'** error when i'm running any npm/npx command

Comment: Editing the `npm` file was the trick for me. When I just edited `npm.cmd` nothing happened. I'm using git bash on Windows. Thumbs up

Comment: Try the suggestion by Lars. See above comments. That works!

Comment: Also please remember to edit the npx.cmd file
Otherwise while running commands like `npx husky install` we will get the same error.

Comment: I needed to edit the `npx` and `npx.cmd` files as well

Comment: It didn't worked for me.

Comment: Its work For Me, I just two file npm and npm.cmd file. Thanks for your solution

Comment: tried all this and nada

Comment: Needed to save as administrator, but got rid of the message, thanks!

Comment: Still the warning is there.. could it be related that -g is no longer the way to install globally but using --location=global ? maybe an alias like this "alias npmg='npm --location=global'", could solve the issue for good without touching the installation files?

Comment: Worked for me (Sept 22).  I did try upgrading npm to the latest version (8.19.2) which I read may solve the problem but it didn't.  Not a great feeling, manually editing these files !

Comment: just clicking won't open the .cmd file. right click and then click edit (on windows).

Comment: Tested this in November 23'. Opened both files normally (using Notepad++) and edited the code. It worked.

Answer (score 201):

Upgrading npm on Windows requires manual steps to ensure that PowerShell/CMD find the new version of npm

### For **Windows** users (thanks [to Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc/72477810#72477810)) [use this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade):

Open PowerShell as **administrator** and run ([information about policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955050/10188661)):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

```
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
```

```
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```

Remember to go back to the initial policy:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

Comment: Today (june, 15 2022) this solved my problem.

Comment: It solved my problem windows 11 (june, 17th 2022)

Comment: Thank you, worked for me as well. Windows 10

Comment: Good question, excelent answer. Just check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/4038991#4038991) question for execution policies. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10(29 June 2022)

Comment: Running a `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` is really very bad advice. At least run as `RemoteSigned`  (In an administrator terminal run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` )

Comment: worked for me. windows 11

Comment: Kind of scary after reading about all of the supply-chain attacks.

Comment: This was the solution for me on Windows 10. WARNING! manualy modify your npm.cmd files ONLY as a las resort.

Comment: @theking2 after completing I again set the policy back to `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force`

Comment: I had to use *Windows* Powershell as admin to run the last 2 lines. Seems to be working.

Comment: I would recommend doing `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process` instead, for security reasons. This limits the policy changes to the current PowerShell session (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2#example-6-set-the-execution-policy-for-the-current-powershell-session)

Comment: this looks the simplest. Worked for me Win 10 (July 20)

Comment: Worked like a charm on windows 10!

Comment: This fixed it for me and is a great solution but I think it needs some explanation about why this works (steal it from the `npm-windows-upgrade` page!)

Comment: This Solved my problem in Windows 11 (09-Feb-2023)

Answer (score 144):

The solution I followed to solve this problem:

1. Go to folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. You have to edit four files named `npm`, `npm.cmd`, `npx`, `npx.cmd`
3. Open the files in a text editor, like [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)
4. Replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global` in all four files
5. Save all (if asked, save as administrator)
6. Good to go!

Comment: This worked when the error was thrown for installing packages in tmp directory

Comment: This has worked for me!

Answer (score 52):

This is a problem on Windows, where npm is called via the `npm.cmd` in your Node.js installation folder.

See line 12.

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

I filed [an issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4980) and this warning got fixed with npm 8.12.1. `-g` is not deprecated anymore.

Comment: good to know! just updated npm to 8.12.1 and it seems fixed. thanks

Comment: I updated to `npm 8.12.1` with `npm install -g npm@latest` but I still get `npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.`

Comment: @Huy You updated to `npm 8.12.1` and when you do `npm -v`, you no longer get this warning?

Comment: Upgrading npm on Windows doesn't work with npm itself like on Linux. You have to use npm-windows-upgrade to update the wrapper script npm.cmd at the right location. https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade

Comment: @DinaM. yes, I no long see that warning. Simply updated npm with `npm -g update`, not sure if that would help.

Comment: @Huy Thanks for your reply. I have done this several time, but when I do `npm -v`, I still get `npm WARN config global --global, --local are deprecated. Use --location=global instead.`
8.12.1

Comment: @DinaM. please try npm-windows-upgrade when on Windows. npm updates itself in the "wrong" directory and not in the node installation path. npm-windows-upgrade will fix that for you.

Comment: @Lars Thank you Lars. Your suggestion did exactly what I wanted to see happen. Cheers

Comment: Working in My case... For change you are open these any program but with adminstrator only

Answer (score 39):

When I check the npm version then I see this error:

```
npm -v
```

Show the error:

> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. 8.11.0

Solution:

1. Go to "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
2. Open [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) in that directory
3. Open four files: npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd
4. Change `prefix -g` to `prefix --location=global`
5. Save and run `npm -v`

[image]

Comment: Nice fix! I just used this, funny you posted this like 3 hours ago :D

Comment: This fixes `npm -v` but not `npm i -g` or `npm i --location=global`. Actuall, no `npm i` command works for me.

Comment: Hi, @AdamJagosz 

closed your terminal / editor and start again. 
If it's not working then restart your system.
If you did the changes, then it's should work.

run: `npm -v -g` & `npm -v`.

This is my current status:

```
D:\MK>npm -v -g
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
8.11.0

D:\MK>npm -v
8.11.0
```

Comment: I have node installed by nvm for Windows, so I replaced the occurences in `C:\Users\adamj\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.16.0`. This is what I get after that:

`npm i --location=global npm@8.13` `npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'`

I should also mention I have no such files at `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: Excellent! The warning is gone, short and precise solution.

Answer (score 17):

Use:

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade

npm-windows-upgrade
```

Select the latest version.

Comment: On Windows 11, I first installed npm 8.16.  Then I ran `npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade` as you suggested.  Thereafter, `npm -v` still displayed:

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Comment: Info: `npm-windows-upgrade` requires Admin Rights.

Answer (score 12):

You didn’t get an error. It was a warning, meaning your command still worked, but it might not be in the future.

Try this:

```bash
npm install --location=global create-react-app
```

And by the way, you can use [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) without installing it as a global dependency. Like this:

```bash
npx create-react-app your-project-name
```

Answer (score 10):

Issue still there on 8.12.1

> npm -v
>
> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> `--location=global` instead.
>
> 8.12.1

It is solved by:

open the file with **run as administrator** other wise you cant edit.

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd

The default code will be:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

Replace above code with the following code:

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix --location=global') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

> npm -v
>
> 8.12.1

Answer (score 5):

If you are on Windows, try the following as administrator:

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

and select version 8.12.1 (latest) for installation.

Comment: Or just `npx npm-windows-upgrade`

Answer (score 4):

Use the latest npm to fix this issue. Use the given command.

```
npm install --global npm@latest
```

Answer (score 3):

This seemed to solve the issue for me:

`npm install  --legacy-peer-deps`

I am running a new install of Windows 11 and installed it.

Answer (score 2):

Change **prefix -g** to **prefix --location=global** in the **npm.cmd** file, as well as the **npx.cmd** file.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to a bug in npm@8.11 which is fixed in 8.12.

I was trying to use Node.js 16.16.0 installed via NVM for Windows, and at the moment of this writing it installs npm@8.11 with it. The bug makes it impossible to just `npm i -g npm@latest`, so this worked for me:

1. Download *npm@8.13* manually from https://libraries.io/npm/npm
2. Check the Node.js location: `nvm root` (the path may be similar to *C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\nvm*)
3. Extract the downloaded `npm` to *v16.16.0\node_modules* in the above directory (I needed to unpack twice — I used [7-Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) to do that).

Comment: This should be at the top, for relevant issue see, https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/5228

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. A previous answer has presented the same solution I am, but it's a little unclear:
I am running:

Node 16.16.0

NPM 8.15.0

I replaced: 'prefix -g' with 'prefix --location=global' in two scripts. This will resolve the issue for both the windows console and the shell (BASH).

Fix --
c:\programfiles\nodejs\npm.cmd //line 12

Line before change:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g' (
```

Line after change:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix --location=global') DO (
```

Fix--
c:\programfiles\nodejs\npm //line 23

Line before change:

```
NPM_PREFIX=`"$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" prefix -g`
```

Line after change:

```
NPM_PREFIX=`"$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" prefix --location=global`
```

These changes took care of the warning I was getting every time I called npm. Hope that this clarifies and helps!

This was tested on Windows 11 Pro, Windows 10 Pro, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64).

I use the following shells:

- GitBash
- PowerShell
- cmd
- Ubunto (WSL)
  Hope that clears things up!

Comment: On Windows, presumably? And using [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), not [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? What version and edition of Windows was this tested on? [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions)? What shell? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73091409/edit), not here in comments (******************* ***without*** ************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: "Answer 18" is not reliable. Depending on the view, the order changes with changing votes. And definitely in a different view (e.g., sorted by oldest first). Perhaps link to it directly (use the "Share" link for that answer)?

Comment: You are correct Peter Mortensen! Sorry about that. I updated the answer for more clarification

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer [from Majbah Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc/72526849#72526849):

***For Windows:***

1. Go to:

   [image]
2. Replace in **all four** files: ***-g -> --location = global***

   [image]

   [image]

Comment: On Windows, presumably? What version and edition was this tested on? [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73204044/edit), not here in comments (******************* ***without*** ************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

### Download the latest version of Node.js for Windows

As countless other answers have mentioned, this is caused by a bug in a version of Node.js (specifically, a version of NPM that is bundled with Node), but what no other answer seems to have yet mentioned is the *simplest* way of solving it.

There's no need to edit any files manually or even run anything in the CLI - just grab the latest version of Node.js from the [Node.js site](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/).

Let it install and compile what it needs to, and you'll end up with the latest version of Node.js that no longer contains this warning.

Besides that, it's good practice to keep up to date with the latest version of Node.js/NPM you can, and it saves you from needing to update later when Node.js 16 is *[EOLed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/end-of-life#Noun)* on September 11th, 2023.

Comment: Yes! I was just about to write the same answer. Please upvote this answer, guys

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error when I installed version 8.12.1 of npm.

Open Command Prompt on Windows or your inbuilt PowerShell terminal in your IDE [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

Update your current npm version to the latest by using this code in your terminal.

`npm i -g npm@latest`

It will first display the same error message for something like two lines. Then proceed to install and update; the updated npm version won't display the error message when you run `npm -v`.

PS: This was tested on a Windows machine running Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Re *"cmd"*: [Implying Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)? And not using [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)? What version and edition of Windows was this tested on? [Windows 10 Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72870667/edit), not here in comments (******************* ***without*** ************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: This didn't fix the issue for me, error's still there on the next run.

Comment: Hello @HashimAziz which system are you running this on? what is the nodejs version?

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code:

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: I am still unable to solve this, tried npm install --force yarn but this doesn't work either

Comment: update your nodejs and npm

Answer (score 1):

It's a folder access issue.

Please follow the below steps:

- Right-click on the project folder
- Click on *Property*
- Uncheck the *Read-only* checkbox
- Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>
- Then try the npm command again

[image]

Comment: On Windows, presumably?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to open and edit the npm.cmd file with [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) if you are logged in as administrator.

Right-click the *npm.cmd* file and choose *Open with Code*.

The file will open in Visual Studio Code.

Change  prefix -g
to      prefix --location=global

When you are finished and attempt to close the file, Visual Studio Code will have a pop up in the lower right corner with the message:

> Failed to save 'npm.cmd': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator.

Click 'Retry as Admin'. The npm.cmd file will be saved and the warning no longer appears at start up.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck with this problem on [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows) and tried all the methods mentioned, but none worked.

This is basically an issue due to the [antivirus software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antivirus_software). It was considering npm as malware and blocking it. So, I excluded npm from being blocking and it worked.

Comment: how did you include npm from being blocked?

Comment: Reinstall npm and you will get a notification from your antivirus that npm is blocked, click here to unblock. Click on that and it will unblock the same.

Comment: What antivirus software? [Windows Defender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Defender)?

Comment: Maybe the defender or any third party application.

Answer (score 0):

A message from the author of the [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started) (CRA):

> [You absolutely should not be installing `react-scripts` globally.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960890)

The Create React App should be installed *locally*:
`npx create-react-app my-app`.

---

Note: in case of issues when uninstalling, see
[Error while creating a Create React App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70358474).

Answer (score 0):

Delete Node.js and install it again, and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. You need to install the following packages:

I am facing the above error, so I simply did these steps:

1. don't create a folder to write command npx create-react-app project-name on the same drive where you install Node.js
2. if you install Node.js on the C: drive, then try to make a folder for practicing react on another drive
3. so I make folder on the D: drive, because I install Node.js on the E: drive
4. open a command prompt on the folder and then write
   the command `npx create-react-folder my-app`

Then your error is solved.

Comment: On Windows, presumably? Why would using different drives make any difference?