# npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. can u give a hand

Tags: node.js, npm

when i was entering this

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

changed 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 2s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 high severity vulnerabilities

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

please help i can`t install for two days.

Comment: The problem is Windows (vs. "npm" or NodeJS per se). 2) It should be fixed in NPM 8.12.1 and higher.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72477810/421195) for details.

Answer (score 0):

## This fixes it

1. Open the node.js installation folder, eg. `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. Open `npm.cmd` with notepad as admin
3. Replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global`, and Save
4. Make the same change to  `npx.cmd` too

Test if it is fixed

If it is not fixed, try updating npm using `npm install npm@latest -g`

[image]