# everytime i install a framework in the first line in terminal it give this error

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

this error
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

```
npm install @vue/cli
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue with Windows. The issue has been already been solved on this thread: [npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-location-glo)