# how to fix this problem? npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead

Tags: node.js, npm

Please some body can help me with this error?

Every thing was good, when suddenly I write `npm index` and VS Code shows this error:

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.        
Debugger attached.
Unknown command: "index"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
```

[image: VS Code terminal showing an NPM error]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you mean to run `npm index.js`? [The warning can be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-location-glo), but the error you're getting says that `npm index` is not a recognized command.

Answer (score 2):

## Try this solution

1. Head to the node.js installation folder, eg. `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. Open the file `npm.cmd` with notepad **as admin**
3. In the file, replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global`, and Save
4. Repeat the step for `npx.cmd` too

Check if it is solved

If it is not solved, update `npm` using the command `npm install npm@latest -g`

[image: Shows the mentioned files opened in an editor]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal was to start the application, right? If that's the case, replace `npm` with `node`.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the version problem of NPM.
if you are using windows then you can follow this

1. Go to folder **C:\Program Files\nodejs**
2. You have to edit four files named **npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd**
3. Open the files in a text editor, like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)
4. Replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global` in all four files

After this Run this command

```
npm i latest-version
```

I'm on Windows and in my case, this worked.
if not working then go through this post here you will get other solutions also
[npm-warn-config-global-post-Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc)