# create-react-app npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

When I create react app for any project then I am facing this on **npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.** How do I fix this problem?

Comment: what is the npm version you are using?

Comment: I encounter this error and this solution works on my side https://stackoverflow.com/a/72526849/17634969

Comment: now my node version (16.15.0) and npm version (8.11.0)

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell as administrator and run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run in terminal
npm install

Comment: This process does not work. :(