# npm Warning: config production; Use --omit=dev Instead

Tags: node.js, npm, config

Every time I run any kind of npm command, I get the following error before the actual output:

```
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.
```

Of course I've come across [similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc) regarding the `-g` flag, and I updated npm to avoid that problem. Some of the workarounds describe editing the `npm` and `npm.cmd` in the program files for node to remove these flags, but for this error in particular, the word `production` occurs *nowhere* in those configuration files. Unhelpfully, npm's warnings don't include a reference to the file that contains this irksome configuration setting.

Can anyone offer advice on where to search for this configuration, or at least how to silence this redundant warning message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And of course, as soon as I ask, I find an answer somewhere else:

I created an error log because of a different npm crash, and when I search the log, I found the config file that was causing the error:

```
C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc
```

Sure enough, I open the file, find `production=false`, delete the necessary line, and now the error has disappeared.

Comment: Where the hell do you find this, This is not in my react project?? please help

Comment: @MysteryMan It's not in your project, it's in the npm AppData folder. Take the file path I posted and adjust it for your system (replacing 'Chris' with your user name), and you should find an `npmrc` file there that you can edit.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be triggered in CI if something sets the env var `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`. Applicable for Heroku, buildpacks, Railway and others.

Seems to be an NPM feature per https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14168:

> Setting NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true during install overrides NODE_ENV always and forever, no matter what I do. Even NODE_ENV=development npm start results in my NODE_ENV being reset to production.

> [Reply] This seems to work as intended according to docs.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to install production by `npm --production` and `install --omit=dev` by `npm --omit=dev` or check you version properly then run a command.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the line `production=false` at the address below and the warning didn't appear anymore.

```
C:\Users\[username]\.npmrc
```

Answer (score 0):

c:\Users\Am.npmrc
My file only contains:

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
npm=install
apollo-boost=react-apollo
graphql=
```

Answer (score -1):

If you got here because you get similar error when running `rfbrowser init` after updating / changes in environment in `RobotFramework` Browser Library, here is the solution:

Clean old browser binaries and node dependencies: `rfbrowser clean-node`
Now you can init: `rfbrowser init`

Source: https://robotframework-browser.org/