# issue with Railway when trying to deploy express mysql app npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Basically what's happening is that when I try to deploy my Express, MySQL, Sequelize website in Railway, it's returning me the following error:
"npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead"
I don't think showing any code is necessary but, if you'd think it is, just let me know.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not familier with Railway deployment, but sounds like if you are running into it only when you try to deploy the app, it wants you to add a --omit=dev flag to your startup command.   Might help if you show the startup config file for railway

Comment: here's a similar question, but there the issue seemed to be with Author's local dev environment. Unless Railway lets you control that on their platform, you might have to just add the flag like it's asking you to.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776325/npm-warning-config-production-use-omit-dev-instead

Comment: Also can you post the full error log you see?