# Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss' (Next.js application)

Tags: npm, webpack, next.js, node-modules, tailwind-css

I recently updated my Node Package Manager in accordance with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72592742/14250712) post. However, now when I create a new Next.js app and run it using `npm run dev`, I get the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\plugins.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\blocks\css\index.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\config\index.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\hot-reloader.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- E:\Code\testing\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

What is causing the error and how do I fix it ? I don't want to build my project using TailwindCSS and hence, do not want to install it.

Edit: I had run the `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` command previously to fix the error. It didn't help. I tried uninstalling it and that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried that? 'npm uninstall tailwindcss' and then 'rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json' and then 'npm install'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](https://flaviocopes.com/fix-postcss-webpack-ruleset-oneof/) post fixed my error. I had a postcss.config.js file in the parent directory that I hadn't noticed. All my Next.js projects were created in a sub-directory and hence, the oversight.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was build a multi stage Docker build which had tailwindcss as a devDependecy in the package builder step. The packages were being installed using yarn wokspaces focus --all --production. As the second stage was being build, tailwindcss was missing since as a devDependency and it wasn't being installed and this error did pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `node_modules` and `.next` folders and follow the guide here:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

Comment: It didn't help. Actually, I don't want to use TailwindCSS in my project at all. I ran my server without modifying the default Next.js installation and the error showed up.

Answer (score 0):

install below command

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

and After install restart the server

Answer (score 0):

in my own case, i install
sudo npm install tailwindcss-animate class-variance-authority clsx tailwind-merge lucide-react