# npm ERR! Invalid Version:

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, package.json

Please I got the below error while setting up an angular project

> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--loca tion=global` instead.
> npm ERR! Invalid Version:

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-02T17_5
> 8_35_503Z-debug-0.log

The version in the package.json is

```
{
  "name": "angular-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message "npm WARN config global \`--global\`, \`--local\` are deprecated. Use \`--location=global\` instead"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc)