# Can't Install font awesome library on React JS

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I copied this command

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

And the error for these three commands is:

> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> `--location=global` instead. npm ERR! code E401 npm ERR! Incorrect or
> missing password. npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your
> password, create an npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor
> authentication then npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password
> in incorrectly. npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password
> at: npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot npm ERR! npm ERR! If you
> were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are npm
> ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again
> with: npm ERR!     npm login
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-06T09_30_05_325Z-debug-0.log

What kind of solution that I need here? While I already follow the guide from official website https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react

Comment: The problem is with your `npm` version, if you search for that you can find the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc

Comment: it gives me the same error

Comment: i already changed it, and follow the instruction there. but nothing changed, the error are still the same