# In React js "normalizeOptions is not a function" when i run "npm start" command

Tags: reactjs

PS G:\Kh Muhib\React and Laravel\parasol\para-health> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> start
> react-scripts start

normalizeOptions is not a function

> **normalizeOptions is not a function**

This error is showing when i run "npm start" command for starting my apps.
This is this main issue. How can i solve it ???
Please response if you have any solutions. I will glad to you. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding of your first issue, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401421/message-npm-warn-config-global-global-local-are-deprecated-use-loc) might help. About your second question, please provide the logs, error stacks, ... .